# Поочерёдное выполнение кода в отдельном потоке

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, сокет

Есть такой код:

```
public class send_data {
    Socket s;
    PrintWriter printWriter;

    public void send(String message, String ip)
    {
        try {
            s = new Socket(ip, 1000);
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            printWriter.write(message);
            printWriter.flush();
            printWriter.close();
            s.close();
        }catch (IOException e){

        }
    }

}
```

Он просто подключается к серверу и скидывает туда что-нибудь.

Суть в чём: есть 4 кнопки. Нужно сделать так, чтобы если нажать 2 кнопки одновременно - чтобы не было такого, что "кто успел - того и тапки", то есть, если нажаты обе одновременно - они вставали в очередь.

Если нажать 1 кнопку, а затем очень быстро вторую - чтобы программа дождалась, пока выполнится отправка сообщения от первой кнопки по сокету, а потом уже от второй.

Слышал, что можно сделать через `newSingleThreadExecutor()`, но не могу понять, как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с помощью `newFixedThreadPool()`:

```
public class send_data {
    Socket s = null;
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    public void send(String message, String ip)
    {
      Future<Void> future = executor.submit(() -> {
         try {
            s = new Socket(ip, 1000);
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            printWriter.write(message);
            printWriter.flush();
         } catch (IOException ignored){}    
         catch (InterruptedException e) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("task interrupted", e);
         }
         finally {
           if (printWriter != null)
              printWriter.close();
           if (s != null)
              s.close();
         }
      });
      future.get();       
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавлю, что если данный метод вызывать в основном потоке, то нажать на вторую кнопку не получится, пока не выполнится `future.get()` (если IDE не распознает здесь NetworkOnMainThreadException), поэтому либо метод нужно вызывать в другом потоке(что странно), либо просто submit`ить Runnable без ожидания его исполнения с помощью Future.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static Thread thread;

private Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
    handler = new Handler();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    switch(id) {
        case R.id.button1:
            button1();
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            button2();
            break;
    }
}

private void button1() {
    final Thread oldThread = thread;
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // ожидание завершения предыдущего потока
            if (oldThread != null) {
                while (oldThread.isAlive()) {
                    Thread.yield();
                }
            }
            // отправка 1 сообщения по сокету
            /* если требуется обращение к UI
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // обращение к UI
                }
            });*/
        }
    };
    thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    thread.start();
}

private void button2() {
    final Thread oldThread = thread;
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // ожидание завершения предыдущего потока
            if (oldThread != null) {
                while (oldThread.isAlive()) {
                    Thread.yield();
                }
            }
            // отправка 2 сообщения по сокету
            /* если требуется обращение к UI
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // обращение к UI
                }
            });*/
        }
    };
    thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    thread.start();
}

}
```